# Why all UI elements on the canvas gets rotated even i just try to rotate selected one

Tags: .net, wpf, rotation, rotatetransform

I have a canvas which has several images. I have cerated attached property that when ever i click right on my mouse the selected image gets rotated by 90 degree.
And it works perfectly for the first rotation. 
The problem is when  i click again then it do not rotate again by 90 degree.

My code is here:

```
sourceElt.MouseRightButtonUp += (sender, e) =>
            {
                RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform(); 
                DragSourceBase advisorDraggable = GetDragSource(sender as DependencyObject);
                if (advisorDraggable.IsDraggable(e.Source as UIElement) == false) return;
                sourceElt = e.Source as UIElement;
                sourceElt.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                myRotateTransform.Angle = 90;
                sourceElt.RenderTransform = myRotateTransform;
                sourceElt.UpdateLayout();
                _isMouseDown = false;
                ifDraggedAfterRotation = true;
                _offsetPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                Mouse.Capture(null);
                _draggedElt = null;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

To solve the previous problem i tried to do change my code like this:

```
 RotateTransform myRotateTransform = new RotateTransform(); //kept it outside rigth button click event
                 sourceElt.MouseRightButtonUp += (sender, e) =>
                {

                    DragSourceBase advisorDraggable = GetDragSource(sender as DependencyObject);
                    if (advisorDraggable.IsDraggable(e.Source as UIElement) == false) return;
                    sourceElt = e.Source as UIElement;
                    sourceElt.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                    myRotateTransform.Angle += 90;  // made it +=
                    sourceElt.RenderTransform = myRotateTransform;
                    sourceElt.UpdateLayout();
                    _isMouseDown = false;
                    ifDraggedAfterRotation = true;
                    _offsetPoint = new Point(0, 0);
                    Mouse.Capture(null);
                    _draggedElt = null;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
```

It solved my previous problem but  another problem arrived that lets say i rotated one image and immediately after i rotate another image , the problem is even if i have not selected the previously rotated image, i just right click on the currently selected image but it rotates both of the image, all the previously selected and the currently selected image.

** How to only rotate the selected image on canvas.**

Comment: The attached property is on the Canvas? When do you subscribe to the event (the += operator in 1st line)? It looks like your event is calling several handlers instead of just one. Can you post more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to increment the `Angle` property of an existing RotateTransform by 90 degrees. If the element's `RenderTransform` property does not already contain a RotateTransform, create and assign it.

```
var element = (UIElement)sender;
var rotateTransform = element.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

if (rotateTransform == null)
{
    rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    element.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
    element.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
}

rotateTransform.Angle += 90;
```

Comment: Et voila that works.. could you please let me know why it was not working before ? Why it was rotating current + revious UI elements while i was just rotating the current element.

Comment: Why it was rotating current and previously rotated UI elements while i was just rotating the current element ?

Comment: Because you were using the same RotateTransform instance for all elements.